# configure: 1: eval: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

```
:~/Qt/5.7/Src$ unset QTDIR; export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
:~/Qt/5.7/Src$ ./configure
+ cd qtbase
+ /home/alexandr/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/configure -top-level 
/home/alexandr/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/configure: 1: eval: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Ошибка конфигурирования, в чём проблема и как исправить?

UPD 1:

```
uname -a
Linux aspire 4.8.0-49-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:38:39 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sh -- version
sh: 0: Can't open version
```

UPD 2:

```
 ls -ltr | tail
drwxrwxr-x  7 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtwebsockets
drwxrwxr-x  4 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtdoc
drwxrwxrwx  7 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtdatavis3d
drwxrwxr-x  7 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qttools
drwxrwxr-x  9 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtdeclarative
drwxrwxr-x 10 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qt3d
drwxrwxr-x  7 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtwinextras
drwxrwxr-x  5 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtdeclarative-render2d
drwxrwxr-x  8 alexandr alexandr  4096 июл  6  2016 qtscript
drwxrwxr-x 16 alexandr alexandr 12288 апр 26 09:40 qtbase
```

UPD 3:

```
qt5/qtbase$ sh --version; ls -ltr | tail
sh: 0: Illegal option --
drwxrwxrwx 13 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 util
drwxrwxrwx  2 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 dist
drwxrwxrwx 17 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 examples
drwxrwxrwx  8 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 tests
drwxrwxrwx 22 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 src
drwxrwxrwx  5 alexandr alexandr    4096 июл  6  2016 qmake
drwxrwxrwx  3 alexandr alexandr    4096 дек 13 09:49 plugins
drwxrwxrwx 97 alexandr alexandr    4096 дек 13 09:49 mkspecs
drwxrwxrwx  3 alexandr alexandr    4096 дек 13 09:49 lib
drwxrwxrwx  9 alexandr alexandr    4096 май 11 14:27 config.tests
```

Comment: configure пишет лог, посмотрите, что там. И добавьте в вопрос больше информации : uname - a, sh - - version.

Comment: @0xdb то что вышло в консоль я вывел, где ещё можно посмотреть данные?

Comment: `sh - -version` без пробела. Логи я не помню как называются. Посмотрите  что последнее писалось - `ls -ltr | tail`

Comment: @0xdb sh --version
sh: 0: Illegal option --
$ sh -- version
sh: 0: Can't open version

Comment: Извените, телефон пытается исправлять - 
 `sh --version`;
`ls -ltr | tail qtbase/`

Comment: @0xdb sh по прежнему показывает то же самое, ./configure после перезагрузки заработало. Правда я ещё ряд мероприятий проводил, но мне кажется они не должны били на это повлиять.

Comment: А что показывает то же самое? Если заработало хорошо. Значит окружение изменилось, т.е. достаточно было новую консоль открыть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57750/discussion-between-shaman888-and-0xdb).

Comment: Running configuration tests...
InterBase support cannot be enabled due to functionality tests!
 Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to /home/alexandr/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/configure to see the final report.
 If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue
 switch (-continue) to /home/alexandr/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/configure to continue.

Comment: ls -ltr | tail qtbase/
tail: ошибка чтения 'qtbase/': Это каталог

Comment: сорри, и на старуху бывает проруха -  `sh --version; ls -ltr | tail`  запустить в папке qtbase/. Я хотел только версию ракушки посмотреть и показал как последний лог найти (там больше информации, чем в консоле).

Comment: @0xdb обновил вопрос

Comment: да, ознакомился с обновлением